# How recursion works in C#

Tags: c#, recursion

Here's my code

```
using System;
public class Program
{
   public static void Method(int flowerInVase)
      {
         if (flowerInVase > 0)
         {
             Method(flowerInVase - 1);
             Console.WriteLine(flowerInVase);
         }
      }

   public static void Main()
   {
      Method(3);
   }
}
```

I am interested in line `Console.WriteLine(flowerInVase);` the method calls itself until it's terminated by the condition. And only after that when the stack is full it pops up each of the method from above and console writes the number starting from the least 1,2,3.

Why the `console.writeline` works only when stack pops up, why it ain't writing the numbers on the way methods go to the termination, like 3,2,1? The compiler uses writeline only when it's done doing recursion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# understanding recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591832/c-sharp-understanding-recursion)

Comment: For what it's worth, people on this site aren't trying to pick on you. It's just that the format of this question is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Not stuck, it's called *stack* :)

Comment: well it was closed so i couldn't reopen it

Comment: The stack won't be full, you just stop filling it when the condition becomes false. If you want to print the numbers in reverse order, call `Console.WriteLine` *before* calling `Method`.

Comment: Just step through with a debugger; that should make it rather clear.

Comment: Follow the execution--why do you think it would go 3, 2, 1?  The recursive call is in front of the WriteLine, you're going to get 1, 2, 3

Comment: I did step through the debugger. it returns to console when it's done with the whole recursion. I just don't understand why, I think i miss the whole algorithm coz of it

Comment: i think it should go 3 2 1 because it firstly calls the method that should print out 3 and after that it calls the method that should print out 2

Comment: In Recurssion, stacks get created and resolved. This can be helpful https://youtu.be/uJLLVYN5iME

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting 1,2,3 because of the way the lines in your `if` statement are ordered.

`Main()` calls `Method(3)`.
`Method(3)` calls `Method(2)` before it has a chance to print "3".  Execution immediately jumps to the top of `Method`; your first call to `Method`, with `flowersinvase=3`, won't complete until the recursive call does.  Likewise, `Method(2)` immediately calls `Method(1)`, and `Method(1)` calls `Method(0)`.

`Method(0)` does nothing and returns to `Method(1)`, exactly where it left off; the next line is your `WriteLine` call, which prints "1" and then returns, which picks up the call to `Method(2)` where it left off, printing "2", and so on for "3".

You would only get "3,2,1" if the methods you called ran to completion before jumping to any methods they called recursively, which is not how C# works.  The thing you have to remember about method calls is that once you call a method, **execution jumps immediately to the start of the method you called; the code after the method call will not execute until the method returns.**

Comment: <quote> returns to Method(1), exactly where it left off - that phrase broke the ice) thank you

Answer (score 10):

The structure of the calls look like this.  Maybe this visualization will help you understand why the numbers print 1, 2, 3 and not 3, 2, 1:

```
Method(3);
  flowerInVase > 0 ?
  Yes - Method(2);
    flowerInVase > 0 ?
    Yes - Method(1);
      flowerInVase > 0 ?
      Yes - Method(0);
        flowerInVase > 0 ?
        No
      WriteLine(1);
    WriteLine(2);
  WriteLine(3);
```

The reason is because your call to `Method(flowerInVase - 1)` comes *before* the call to `WriteLine(flowerInVase)`. Execution jumps to a different copy of the method before it has a chance to print the number it is on.

Comment: I thought WriteLine is within the body of a method so it should have been done all together and then turn to next method

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio you can step over each line as it is called with F11 (default key binding). You'll see that when executing hits the call to `Method(flowerInVase - 1);` it immediately jumps to the top of the method again - but as a new method on the stack. The call stack display will reflect this.

Comment: thank you. Yes I did that. But after all your explanations guys I have a clue what I have seen while pressing F11. I saw it jumped to writeline after all recursion was done, i just didn't know why coz as i told before i though it should have done the whole body of the methodand only then invoke the one that was within

Answer (score 2):

Because it does this:

```
flowerInVase = 3
call Method(3)
    call Method(2)
        call Method(1)
        WriteLine(1)
    WriteLine(2)
WriteLine(3)
```

Output then is:

```
1
2
3
```

If you reverse the lines:

```
    Console.WriteLine(flowerInVase);
    Method(flowerInVase - 1);
```

It will print first, then recurse, so it will print 3, 2, 1 instead.

Answer (score 1):

> The compiler uses writeline only when it's done doing recursion.

It does that *because you told it to do that*. In your code, first perform the recursion (call `Method()`) and only when that finishes, you write the number.

If you want to write the number first, before performing recursion, you need to switch of statements in your code:

```
public static void Method(int flowerInVase)
{
   if (flowerInVase > 0)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(flowerInVase);
       Method(flowerInVase - 1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why the console.writeline works only when stuck pops up, why it ain't
>   writing the numbers on the way methods go to the termination, like
>   3,2,1?

Because your `Method(flowerInVase - 1);` is called *before* `Console.WriteLine(flowerInVase);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the code execution line by line this makes sense. If you break it down what it really is saying is you always create a new instance of the recursive call before you ever get a chance to write anything to the console. Only once you have created all the calls you are allowed to (your if-statement fails) is the control of the thread returned to 
the existing methods.

```
Create method -> check parameter 
  -> create method - > check parameter
    -> create method -> check parameter
      etc. etc.
    -> print value
  -> print value
-> print value
```

So now that you see it is returning control back up the way it was called. The last called function needs to complete its operation before the one that called it can complete.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should investigate what it means to be recursive.  This is a very simple example of a recursive method: that is, a method which calls itself.  Recursion has many uses in many fields, especially programming, but that's not what you asked and not what I will answer.

If you read the code line by line, you will see that `Method(3)` is called, which in turn calls `Method(2)`, and most importantly, it makes this call BEFORE it outputs the value 3.  So therefore, `Method(2)` will execute in its entirety before the final line from `Method(3)` is output.  Again, `Method(2)` calls itself BEFORE it outputs 2, so the entirety of `Method(1)` will execute before this.

A simple flowchart:

```
Main() -> Method(3)               
              --->calls Method(2)
                            --->calls Method(1)
                                          -Method(0) not viable
                                          -if statement failed
                                          -Outputs '1'
                            -Outputs '2'
              -Outputs '3'
End of Main()
```