# switching values in a recursion method

Tags: c#, function, recursion, c#-4.0

for learning the recursion, i extend the recursion method from following link:
[how recursion works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613273/how-recursion-works?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
followoing is my code:

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Method(3,1,2);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static void Method(int flowerInVase, int a, int b)
        {
            if (flowerInVase > 0)
            {
                Method(flowerInVase - 1,b,a);
                Console.WriteLine(+flowerInVase+", "+a+" ,"+b);

            }

        }
```

following is the output:

```
1, 1 ,2
2, 2 ,1
3, 1 ,2
```

I understood stack concept, but not understanding switching of values a and b in 3rd iteration. after calling method(3) recursively, when flowerInVase=1, shouldn't the values of a=2 and b=1 respectively, as the recursive function method(flowerInVase - 1,b,a) gets called. Need to understand how recursive function works in this case

Comment: Just follow your logic, its pretty straight forward.

Comment: First Method(3,1,2) is called, then Method(2,2,1), then Method(1,1,2), and then Method (0,2,1). In Method (0,2,1), the code inside if condition will not get executed. After which Method(1,1,2) continues its execution and writes 1, 1, 2 to console. Followed by 2,2,1 and 3,1,2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of `a` and `b` are reversed with respect to the *previous* call - precisely because the call is

```
Method(flowerInVase - 1, b, a);
```

You can see from your output that when `flowerInVase` is 2, the value of `a` is 2 and the value of `b` is 1. That's what this line means:

```
2, 2 ,1
```

So looking at it, we have:

```
Method(flowerInVase -1, b, a);
// flowerInVase is 2
// b is 1
// a is 2
```

So that final call is equivalent to:

```
Method(1, 1, 2);
```

... which is what your final output shows.

The important point is that it's using the values of `a` and `b` in the *currently executing* method, not the values in the "top-most" method.

Comment: in essence does it mean that in 3rd iteration, b is a and a is b. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @NIMISHDESHPANDE: In each call, `b` has the value that `a` did in the previous call, and vice versa.